# meteorhacks:npm Meteor.npmRequire doesn't work when following the instructions

Tags: node.js, meteor

Currently using meteor 1.4

I have followed instructions for [meteorhacks](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm). However, I continue to get `Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.npmRequire is not a function` when following the instructions and no matter where I put it does it ever work.

All that I am trying to achieve is I want to use the `net` module in Meteor for some socket communication. Note that I am only focusing on the client side of this.

Googling the error hasn't provided any working solutions.

Not sure if this could be affect it, but I am trying to call it in a .jsx file as I am tying some rendering stuff with ReactJS.

Edit:

I have even tried this [tutorial](https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client-npm/) and end up with it not working. When I try to call the variable I get an empty object.

Meteor has been proving to be more and more difficult to manage. Trying to deal with Meteor itself, React components as well as other node type packages, but have to be imported a certain when. Always tend to have issue importing certain things because of React.

Comment: I believe `net` is a server side module, therefore you can not use it in your browser

Comment: are you aware of any socket modules that can work in the browser.

Comment: There are plenty of them, I would recommend [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for Meteorhacks/npm (https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm)

> **Use Npm Modules with Your Meteor App**
>
> Using With Meteor 1.3
>
> Meteor 1.3 has the build in NPM support. So, in Meteor 1.3 this
>   package won't add anything.

Which basically means from 1.3, npm support is native in Meteor, you don't need to use this package any more.